# How to turn HttpMessageNotReadableException into human friendly message without exposing implementation details?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

When building a REST API with Spring Boot a *HttpMessageNotReadableException* seems to be thrown when for example the JSON request body is incorrect and thus cannot be parsed.

Suppose a REST API endpoint expects the following JSON request body:

```
{ "email": "myemail@email.com" }
```

However, instead the following JSON request body is provided (missing quotation mark):

```
{ "email: "myemail@email.com" }
```

The result is the following exception message:

> JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting
> a colon to separate field name and value; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
> ('m' (code 109)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and
> value\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 15]

Now, this exception message contains useful information such as the unexpected character, what character was expected instead, and the location. However the exception message also leaks implementation details which is undesirable for my use case.

The *HttpMessageNotReadableException* does not expose methods to obtain the useful information separately. Furthermore, the exception message exists in different "flavors" and it does not use a common structure, thus string parsing seems infeasible.

Therefore, my question is: **How to turn HttpMessageNotReadableException into human friendly message without exposing implementation details?**

Answer (score 0):

You can dig out the underlying `JsonParseException` that you see in your stack trace via the method `Throwable.getCause` that `HttpMessageNotReadableException` inherits from `Throwable`. It might require recursive application depending on how deep it's buried in your stack trace. `JsonParseException` has several getters that can return some of the info you want.

However, I'd not bother with reformatting this error message. It will simplify debugging if you leave it as is.

Comment: Error messages that contain implementation details can't be returned in production environment due to the obvious security issues, for example when working on an API that validates client's request and returns validation errors. Thus having a way to get a clean message without implementation details is a necessity.